# Filter specific strings from nested list of strings

Tags: python, filtering, nested-lists, defaultdict

I need to filter strings from a nested list of strings. I've read up existing answers and tried to use `defaultdict` to do it:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def isRelevant(string_set):
    if string_set.find("a1") != -1 or string_set.find("a2") != -1 or string_set.find("b3") != -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False  

def data_filter(string_matrix):
  new_list = []
  for string_set in string_matrix:
    temp = filter(isRelevant, string_set)
    new_list.append(temp)
  return new_list

def main(): 
  string_matrix = [ ['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3'],['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3'] ]

  filtered_strings = data_filter(string_matrix)
  for each in filtered_strings:
    print each,

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The above is a working example of a list of nested lists containing strings.

This example works well and returns the expected output [`'a1', 'a2', 'b3'] ['a1', 'a2', 'b3']`

What I am now attempting to create is a situation where the output is

```
[ ['a1','a2','a3'],['c1','c2','c3'] ]
```

The aim is to basically say "if you find 'a1', filter just for 'aX' and if you find 'c1', filter just for 'cX'. 
Meaning to filter specific strings according to a specific string.

I tried to change the `isRelevant` method to:

```
def isRelevant(string_set):
    if string_set.find("a1") != -1:
      if string_set.find("a1") != -1 or string_set.find("a2") != -1 or string_set.find("a3") != -1:
        return True
    elif string_set.find("c1") != -1 or string_set.find("c2") != -1 or string_set.find("c3") != -1:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

The code above is meant to filter for 'aX' if 'a1' is found, and filter otherwise for 'cX'.

The output I get is:

```
['a1'] ['a1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

What might be the problem with my code in the second step, and is there a better way to perform 'filter specific strings according to a specific string'?

Comment: Did you try printing data, or conditional expression results? were there any clues?

Comment: What happens if it finds both? Will it filter for both `a`'s and `c`'s? You should clarify that.

Comment: wwii - Which data should I print? there are no variables except the list itself..

Comment: vasilis G. - the aim is to filter 'a' and only if no 'a' is found, filter for 'c', that's why i tried using 'elif'

Comment: You're calling `isRelevant()` only on single strings. How are they supposed to know whether they're in a list that contains an `a1` or a `c1`?

Comment: Also, `if string_set.find("a1") != -1` can be replaced more readably with `if "a1" in string_set`.